# How do I use expressions to parse data from email?

Tags: regex, parsing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am using Microsoft flow to bring email data into a spreadsheet.  I need to pull customer # from the subject (numeric string always at the end) & date/time stamp from body.  Completely ignorant as to how to use expressions to parse the data I need.  Can someone help?

Below are examples of said subject & body:

```
Subject:  00:02:52 - Michael Weslosky truck 803690(610) SN: G85A210B2E5C arrived at customer V7880

Body:  David Shiflett, 796969(613) SN: G8FC2109E436 arrived at 62519 - 1046 Millwood Pike, Winchester, VA 22602, USA on 06/12/20 20:56:46. The odometer reading was 160,566 miles at the time of arrival.
```

Comment: I should have specified, my apologies.  I'm looking for the code (expression) language on the parsing side (Microsoft flow) in order to feed the data I need onto the google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "customer (.+)$"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+"))))
```

[image: 0]